# How to get a Sagemaker notebook onto GitHub?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, amazon-sagemaker

I have a Sagemaker notebook that I would like to move to a GitHub repository. I thought perhaps I should download the files locally, then I can easily push to git. But I cannot figure out how to download the folder to my local computer. Then I though, perhaps there is a way using the AWS CLI to move directly from Sagemaker to git? I've made many google searches that are unable to answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off the answer given by @mokugo-devops, I was able to link my existing notebook to my GitHub account.

First, I followed the directions posted in the link provided in his answer to set up my GitHub repo with my AWS account on the CLI, then I used the following command to edit my existing notebook:

```
aws sagemaker  update-notebook-instance \
--notebook-instance-name <value> \
--default-code-repository <saved-github-repo-name-in-AWS>
```

my notebook instance is now linked my GitHub repo.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually setup your notebook in SageMaker with a link to [GitHub](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/amazon-sagemaker-notebooks-now-support-git-integration-for-increased-persistence-collaboration-and-reproducibility/).

You can then launch a Notebook instance that will pull in your Notebook, whilst allowing you to commit the changes that you've made and push to your remote repository.

Further instructions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/nbi-git-repo.html

Comment: unfortunately I already created the notebook. I didnt think to add the git account before creating it. Is there any way to add the current notebook to my git repo?

Comment: Hi, if you create the git repository and setup, it seems at least by CLI you can use the default-code-repository on your notebook: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker/update-notebook-instance.html. You should be able to modify from the console, not sure if notebook will need to be switched off first